# Is it possible to have nulls in Foreign keys in any ANSI SQL database?

Tags: sql

Is it possible to have nulls in Foreign keys in any ANSI SQL database?

Comment: Yes. Check out Vincent's answer on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767657/how-do-i-create-unique-constraint-that-also-allows-nulls-in-sql-server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sure, in all databases it's possible.
unless the field is declared as NOT NULL.