# Database Design for Multi-use Table

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling

Say you have multiple "things" which can each have one or more comments attached. Product and Order, for instance. How should the tables be structured....

1. Product, Order, Comment, ProductComment { ProductID, CommentID }, OrderComment { OrderID, CommentID }
2. Product, Order, ProductComment { ProductID, Text }, OrderComment { OrderID, Text }
3. Product, Order, Comment { ProductID, OrderID, Text }

Using SQL Server 2008, by the way.

Thoughts, opinions?

Comment: Take a look at a **[similar question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050784/defining-multiple-foreign-keys-in-one-table-to-many-tables/4051523#4051523)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely only use one Comment table, so you don't have to duplicate Comment information (e.g. timestamp, flagged_for_moderation, etc).  Having two fields in comment is nice because it makes it clear that it's a one-to-many link.  I'd probably lean towards that over multiple linking tables, though I do appreciate that you only have rows in the linking table when there's a link, versus having half the values be `NULL`. Perhaps in a very large database with more things that can be commented, you might go for the linking tables.

Comment: Agreed about the duplication aspect. I like the linking tables except I don't like the extra step to get to the Comment table.

Comment: Yeah, the linking table does make your queries more complicated. Using multiple columns instead also means that if you get all Comments, you can tell what kind of comment they are without doing any JOIN at all, and if you use IDs in URLs (or other references), you may be able to just link directly to the item being commented on.

Comment: Another reason I like the linking table is that you can add additional fields as needed. Maybe the ProductComment table also has some fields which are related strictly to that combination of Product\Comment.

Comment: I would say use the linking table if you need the extra fields or if you expect to soon. It's really hard to future-proof a schema. Also, just as a side note, I often use the convention Product_Comment for linking tables, to distinguish between them and normal camel-cased table names.

Comment: I think the linking table option is the most flexible and future-proof. And these tables can be treated as pass-through tables since they are really one-to-one. So code could be generated to expose the Comment table directly on the Product table, skipping the linking table altogether.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the `Order/Product` tables should stay as is.

The `Comments` table can be

```
CommentID
EntityID
EntityType
Comment
```

Where `EntityType` will then tell you to which table the `EntityID` belongs (`ProductID/OrderID`)

Comment: Thanks. The reason I didn't list this option is because this breaks the foreign keys. I don't really want to check EntityType to determine which table to look in to fetch the Entity.

Comment: This does have the limitation that you can't use explicit foreign keys in a database that supports them (e.g. InnoDB), which means you can't really utilize features like `CASCADE`. I appreciate that it reduces the number of tables necessary, and in many cases that's good, but it's not universally worth it.

Comment: I probably would lean towards this because it gives you the flexibility to add another type in the future without having to create any more ORM-type of code to support it (or add another table or field). Sure you cannot do cascades anymore, but in these specialty situations you have to make some compromises.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the `entityID`, `entityType` method, because you can't use foreign key constraints, you could take a mixed strategy, something like

```
COMMENT(commentID, comment, productID, orderID, ....)
```

with ...'s as an additional column for each commentable table.

Comment: this maybe could work, but astander's answer is how it is normally done.

Comment: This is my option #3. Not sure if I like it though....I'm leaning toward option 1.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy I think astander's answer is worse than the 3 options I've listed.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy Can you provide some examples showing that this is how it is "normally" done? ORMs like Doctrine don't even *support* methods like that in their built-in many-to-many relationships. And there are some obvious disadvantages. Needless to say, I am dubious.

Comment: well, the ORM in both Django and Rails works in the manner suggested by astander

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: Well, Django *supports* that. You have to explicitly define a [Generic relation](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/generic_relations/). But still, good examples. I should figure out how much of a speed difference that would entail.

Comment: Django supports it exceptionally well, with the `django.contrib.contenttypes` app, which is in the vanilla distro.

Answer (score 0):

If you go with the linking tables and you have more than 2 or 3 “types” that can be linked to comment then start thinking about a code generated to create all the SQL you need.    You will very soon have a 101 linking tables and lots of table definition SQL to maintain.

If you use GUIDS for all your IDs and don’t mind not having foreign keys defined in the database, then there are other options, but I don’t think that the style of database schema you have.

This is one of the use cases that make me think the relational model is a pain in the neck!

Answer (score 0):

I am a fan of adding the entity ID and entity type columns to add add flexibility without having the additional join.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I find this to be a pretty dirty, non-OO way of structuring a database. You're losing the DB logic to validate that the entity actually exists. Of course you can do this in code, but from a DB standpoint it is not a very clean solution.

Comment: @Josh M - You will have to consider the space trade off.  Not everything can be perfect.  This is a very OO way of doing things - the Entity is polymorphic as it represents many different types in one table.