# Creating a MySQL table with two foreign keys in a cross-reference table

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

This probably comes from some lack of knowledge or plain stupidity, but I would like to understand how to create foreign keys in a cross reference table:

For example, I have two tables, item and image

```
CREATE TABLE `item` (
    `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `description` MEDIUMTEXT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `image` (
    `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `file` VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    `caption` VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I want to reference any image to any item, so I create a cross-reference table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `item_image` (
    `item` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,#foreign key
    `img` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,#foreign key
    PRIMARY KEY(`item`,`img`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

But the item_image table contains columns that are foreign keys, so I try to constrain them like this

```
CREATE TABLE `item_image` (
    `item` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `img` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`item`,`img`),
    FOREIGN KEY(`item`)
        REFERENCES `item` (`id`) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(`img`)
        REFERENCES `image` (`id`) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

So that if the image or the item get removed, the database would remove the cross reference too.

I have read lots of resources on the web, and stackoverflow, and it is often suggested that there should be no problem in doing what I want
[Defining multiple foreign keys in one table to many tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050784/defining-multiple-foreign-keys-in-one-table-to-many-tables)

but MySQL gives me this generic error

> Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'test.item_image' (errno: 150)

I need some help to understand what exactly MySQL is complaining about.

**Edit:**

I execute the queries in MySQL Workbench 5.2.39 CE if that matters...

MySQL version: 5.5.16

Comment: Actually, I just executed those statements and it works perfectly...

Comment: @Konerak what the heck!? why do I keep getting these errors that no one else gets...

Comment: its working in sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7cc08/1

Comment: @Yuri: http://pastebin.com/twrVUZVe - what version MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Konerak as far as I know it should be MySQL 5.5.16

Comment: Are your tables empty? If not, you either want to make sure all the constraints are met, the table is made empty, or you set foreign-key-checks to off?

Comment: @Nanne tables are empty, `SELECT @@foreign_key_checks;` gives 1, so they are on.

Comment: @Konerak I found the error thanks to your pastebin and gordatron's sqlfiddle and Nanne made me realize the source of the problem. I was creating the item_image table before the image table... It's always something stupid like this that gets me. Let's see if I'm not the only one.

Comment: Should I edit the question and post the answer, or just delete the question?

Comment: @YuriKolovsky: Post as an answer to your own question - it may help others in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was creating the `item_image` table before the `image` table, and this caused me to get the MySQL error 150

I feel stupid now :)

the error can also be caused by other reasons, in which case you should check

[MySQL Creating tables with Foreign Keys giving errno: 150](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457305/mysql-creating-tables-with-foreign-keys-giving-errno-150)

http://verysimple.com/2006/10/22/mysql-error-number-1005-cant-create-table-mydbsql-328_45frm-errno-150/

Comment: Beside that you solved the issue, **the design is wrong**. It is not a relation of *Many to Many*, but a *1 to Many* (1 art. Many images). So you don't need to use a cross-reference table, you should store a foreign key in the `image` table.

Comment: @Lucio some articles re-use images from other articles, so the design is not wrong.