# Multiple foreign keys to many tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following classes:

```
public class Project
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
    // Navigation
    public virtual IEnumerable<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    //public virtual IEnumerable<Message> Messages { get; set; } // ???
}

public class Task
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
    // Navigation
    //public virtual IEnumerable<Message> Messages { get; set; } // ???
}

public class Message
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    ...
    // Foreign Keys ??
}
```

Basically:

- **Project** will have many **Task**
- **Project** will have many **Message**
- **Task** will have many **Message**
- Each **Message** will belong to either a **Project** or **Task**

How will I write the database, as well as write the EF code to achieve this? I want to be able to use Linq syntax for eg. `List<Message> messages = project.Messages.ToList();`

I have found this [alternative design](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4050811/459021) but not sure how the navigation properties will look.

Comment: You're using code-first design, right?  Do you need to manually add the SQL tables and keys for this?

Comment: Sorry - Yes, it's code-first. I will take care of the sql tables (prefer to), but need to work this out first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are pretty much there.  Could you try this?

```
public class Project
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
    // Navigation
    public virtual IEnumerable<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
    // Navigation
    public virtual IEnumerable<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    ...
    public int? ProjectId {get;set;}
    public int? TaskId {get;set;}

    public virtual Project {get;set;}
    public virtual Task {get;set;}
}
```