# Multiple nullable foreign keys in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, foreign-keys

I am in the process of designing a table for a promotion. I can promote three types of entities: article, photo and forum thread.

Initially I thought about creating one table with three foreign keys where only one would be set.

```
promotion: 
- id
- id_article
- id_photo
- id_thread
- promotion_type
- ... other properties

 article:
 - id
 - .. other properties

 photo:
 - id
 - .. other properties

 thread:
 - id
 - .. other properties
```

Is t a good approach? After initial thoughts it does look like there could be something "prettier" done here. `promotion_type` indicates which foreign keys tables should be joined.

Comment: `promotion_type` seems superfluous.

Comment: by design it's there to save some joining time, because we don't have to join all tables, only those which are needed.

Comment: that can also be determined by which id_ has a value correct?

Comment: Seems like a good point, sql server won't try to join null value even if I request it in the query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defining multiple foreign keys in one table to many tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050784/defining-multiple-foreign-keys-in-one-table-to-many-tables)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having 3 columns (id_article, id_photo, id_thread), just add one column.. Call it PromotionID for example, then you can still use PromotionType column to determine which table to tie.

The Promotion table would be as follows:-promotion: 
- id
- PromotionID(either id_article, id_photo or id_thread)
- promotion_type
- ... other properties

Comment: I wouldn't like to weaken data integrity. With FK, sql server will check whether this id actually exist in the other table.

Comment: I have a similar usecase and if I follow this approach then I'll have to make sure the id exist manually and I'll have to fetch the data from the related table manually, any simpler way of doing this?