# What's the best way to design multiple 1 to 1 relation within Postgre

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I would like to know if there's a better way to design this kind of relationships within Postgre:

[image: Database 1:1 relationship]

Basically, I've got some entities that are either an `EntityA`, an `EntityB` or an `EntityC`. I will have plenty of other relationships between entities and other stuff (like `Comment` in this case) so I've got this generic `Entity` that defines which type of `Entity` it's linked to.

As an example, if we have an EntityA linked to a comment, the Entity entry will look like:

`type: EntityA
entity_a_id: x
entity_b_id: null
entity_c_id: null`

Is there a better way to design this?

Comment: Can a record in your Entity table have an a, b, and c ID?

Comment: Yes, only one at a time (which is defined in field `type`)

Comment: This is going to cause you much pain later - you will end up writing statements that join from Entity to EntityA B and C every time, since it must cover any scenario. How different are the entities that they should be on different tables and not hosted on a single table?

Comment: ?So no, a record in Entity table can't have a, b and c at the same time. Although [this link](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph) is angled at SqlServer and C# code, options for modelling the inheritance of multiple subclasses are typically Table per Type (kind of what you've done) and Table per Hierarchy (big fat table with everything). But you wouldn't have the type discriminator AND the entity subclass ids in the base table - you can share the same entity id primary key on the subclass tables.

Comment: In that case, this is a terrible way to model it. Provide some sample data that would be in the tables.

Comment: Each entity is going to be very different, like totally different. Some are going to be a person, another one will be a location, another one will be a scenario. The only thing they have in common will be a name and a photo. The thing is that I need to reference them as if they were the same entity cause all the features on the project applies to every entities (eg: you can comment anyone of them)

Comment: Why not just have table EntityAttrib with ID and TypeID being the Key and you join from entity to EntityAttrib on Type and ID.  it's one join 100% of the time using a combined key.

Comment: xQbert: Can you elaborate a bit? I'm not sure to get it

Comment: seems a bit off, take a look at this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050784/defining-multiple-foreign-keys-in-one-table-to-many-tables/4051523#4051523

Answer (score 1):

This seems a good fit for the  [Table Inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/tutorial-inheritance.html) feature

```
CREATE TABLE entity (
  -- columns that are shared among all entities
);

CREATE TABLE entity_a (
  -- columns that are unique for this entity type
) INHERITS (entity);

CREATE TABLE entity_b (
  -- columns that are unique for this entity type
) INHERITS (entity);
```

This way, entity types do not include columns of other types

Comment: I won't be able to list all available entities at once and identify them by ID. One of the use case will be to mention one of the entities like with @ on Facebook, so I need a list with unique IDs of every entities at once

Answer (score 0):

How different are the entities?

Why not just

```
CREATE TABLE Entity
(
    EntityId int,
    EntityType enum(A, B, C),
    FieldValue varchar(255)
)
```

or if the field values are significantly different and don't make sense in a single column,

```
CREATE TABLE Entity
(
    EntityId int,
    EntityType enum(A, B, C),
    FieldValueX varchar(255),
    FieldValueY varchar(255),
    FieldValueZ varchar(255)
)
```

Comment: I don't want to end up with a huge table containing multiple useless fields depending which entity is represented. Actually there will be 5 completely different entities with at least 10 unique fields.